# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "title"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My application have dropdown which shows timings of a batch run
`<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-siTime-container" title="10 AM - 11 AM">10 AM - 11 AM</span>`
After I click the dropdown beside the dropdown I will get values to select.

```
<ul class="select2-results__options ps-container ps-theme-default ps-active-y" role="tree" id="select2-siTime-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" data-ps-id="e0656a98-863d-cab8-ceca-763253acd3a0">
  <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-siTime-result-sl6p-TIME_6" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">6 AM - 7 AM</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-siTime-result-ogb9-TIME_7" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">7 AM - 8 AM</li>
  <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-siTime-result-wx7b-TIME_8" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">8 AM - 9 AM</li>
```

When I try to select dropdown I'm seeing error that

> Element should have been select but was title

My Code:

```
Select mycombo = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("title")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-labelledby='select2-siTime-container']/span[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);
mycombo.selectByIndex(4);
```

Comment: If your question is still unsolved, can you please provide some more information as below ?

Comment: 1. Please add some more code from the HTML DOM. 2. Which value do you want to select ? 3. Can you confirm if it is a simple Dropdown or a modal Dropdown ? 4. Can you add a snapshot of the Dropdown ?

Answer (score 2):

`Select` class can be used only for `<select>` tags. To select an option from this dropdown click on it and then click on the option. Something like

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("select2-siTime-results"));
dropdown.click();
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.className("select2-results__option"));
options.get(4).click();
```

Comment: Guy - I have tried changing the get() - webelement list but always it clicks only one option. ? if I enter get(3) even then it is clicking same element instead of the one above in the li class.